# Convert Latitude and Longitude values to a place name and display it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

Is there a way of converting a Latitude and Longitude value into a place name and then being able to display that name on a HTML page?

```js
if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
  let watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
    let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log(latitude, longitude);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error.code);
  }, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
  });
  console.log(watchID);
} else {
  console.log("Not Supported");
}
```

The code can return the latitude and longitude and they can be displayed, I want to get the specific place if possible and display it on the page or record it in a table?

Comment: The name for the practice of converting a set of lat/lng coords to a human-readable location is called Reverse Geocoding. The Google Maps API can do this for you, although note that the free version is limited in the number of calls you can make: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need three things:

1. A list of places with their coordinates. That's sort of out of scope for this site.
2. A distance function. You can either use the cosine rule or haversine rule for that.
3. A nearest neighbour algorithm that's better than O(n). For that, you can e.g. partition your set from 1, google "sphere triangular tesselation" for that, and then you can optimize your nearest neighbour algorithm.